# Is it possible to update the sound options after boot?

Tags: sound, hdmi

I run my computers display via HDMI into an AV Receiver which then goes to the screen.

I've noticed that if the AV Receiver isn't selected to the computers channel when booting the computer, Ubuntu won't attempt to direct sound through the HDMI port and the HDMI options won't be available in the sound menu.

Does anyone know of a way to get Ubuntu to see the sound option if it's not initially available? At the moment I have to reboot

---

Output of lsmod when I can't output sound through my AV receiver.

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uvcvideo               81065  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15682  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              149725  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
snd_usb_audio         165882  1 
media                  21963  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_usbmidi_lib        29779  1 snd_usb_audio
joydev                 17344  0 
hid_logitech_dj        18469  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23256  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27605  0 
vboxdrv               418013  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   19543  2 
rfcomm                 69509  14 
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 52566  0 
btusb                  32448  0 
bluetooth             446190  33 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
arc4                   12608  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  2 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
iwlmvm                217797  0 
mac80211              660592  1 iwlmvm
intel_rapl             18783  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18786  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143592  0 
kvm                   459835  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77185  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
aesni_intel           152552  2 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13287  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13944  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20360  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
serio_raw              13434  0 
i915                  917814  7 
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
mei_me                 19742  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
nouveau              1234956  0 
iwlwifi               183038  1 iwlmvm
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_intel          30420  7 
snd_compress           19200  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      15172  1 snd_soc_core
cfg80211              510218  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_hda_controller     35152  1 snd_hda_intel
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
snd_hda_codec         139675  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ttm                    97680  1 nouveau
mei                    87931  1 mei_me
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
drm_kms_helper         61627  2 i915,nouveau
snd_hwdep              17698  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
drm                   310919  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
snd_pcm               104102  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
shpchp                 37040  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13406  2 i915,nouveau
snd_rawmidi            30876  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i2c_hid                18719  0 
snd                    87611  31 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
hid                   110426  6 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
video                  20128  2 i915,nouveau
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0 
dw_dmac                12835  0 
mac_hid                13227  0 
dw_dmac_core           24298  1 dw_dmac
i2c_designware_platform    12979  0 
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
8250_dw                13551  0 
spi_pxa2xx_platform    23079  0 
acpi_pad               17942  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               106593  0 
ahci                   34062  3 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
e1000e                230184  0 
alx                    36680  0 
ptp                    19445  1 e1000e
mdio                   13561  1 alx
pps_core               19333  1 ptp
sdhci_acpi             13351  0 
sdhci                  43448  1 sdhci_acpi
```

Output of when I can output sound through my AV receiver:

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uvcvideo               81065  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15682  1 videobuf2_core
snd_usb_audio         165882  1 
videodev              149725  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
snd_usbmidi_lib        29779  1 snd_usb_audio
media                  21963  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 17344  0 
hid_logitech_dj        18469  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23256  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27605  0 
vboxdrv               418013  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 52566  0 
btusb                  32448  0 
bnep                   19543  2 
rfcomm                 69509  14 
bluetooth             446190  33 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
arc4                   12608  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  2 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
iwlmvm                217797  0 
intel_rapl             18783  0 
mac80211              660592  1 iwlmvm
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18786  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
coretemp               13441  0 
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
kvm_intel             143592  0 
kvm                   459835  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
aesni_intel           152552  2 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13287  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13944  1 aesni_intel
snd_compress           19200  1 snd_soc_core
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm_dmaengine      15172  1 snd_soc_core
cryptd                 20360  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
nouveau              1234956  0 
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77185  1 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
serio_raw              13434  0 
iwlwifi               183038  1 iwlmvm
snd_rawmidi            30876  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
i915                  917814  7 
cfg80211              510218  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_hda_intel          30420  7 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
snd_hda_controller     35152  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
snd_hda_codec         139675  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ttm                    97680  1 nouveau
snd_hwdep              17698  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               104102  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
drm_kms_helper         61627  2 i915,nouveau
mei_me                 19742  0 
mei                    87931  1 mei_me
drm                   310919  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
shpchp                 37040  0 
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i2c_algo_bit           13406  2 i915,nouveau
snd                    87611  31 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
i2c_hid                18719  0 
hid                   110426  6 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
dw_dmac                12835  0 
dw_dmac_core           24298  1 dw_dmac
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0 
video                  20128  2 i915,nouveau
mac_hid                13227  0 
i2c_designware_platform    12979  0 
8250_dw                13551  0 
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
spi_pxa2xx_platform    23079  0 
acpi_pad               17942  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               106593  0 
e1000e                230184  0 
ahci                   34062  3 
alx                    36680  0 
ptp                    19445  1 e1000e
libahci                32424  1 ahci
mdio                   13561  1 alx
pps_core               19333  1 ptp
sdhci_acpi             13351  0 
sdhci                  43448  1 sdhci_acpi
```

Comment: Can you post to http://paste.ubuntu.com the output of `lsmod` when you have the problem and once when you don't?  Then I can compare and maybe come up with something...  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: have you got it solved yet, Gaunt?

Comment: I no longer have the AVR unit and don't think I ever got it working 100% of the time :(

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether it's because HDMI is not the "*default* device", when it's not attempted at boot, for [ALSA](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/alsa).

Even if that's the case I cannot test currently if this works without rebooting.

So you could give a try to this

## **by Jochen Voss at http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/alsa**:

> ## Is ALSA present in your kernel?
>
> Check for the presence of a `/proc/asound/` directory. If the directory exists, you have ALSA support in your kernel.

...

> ## What sound cards are known to the system?
>
> Check the contents of the `/proc/asound/cards` file. Each entry there corresponds to a (real or simulated) sound card. On my system I
>   get the following:
>
> ```
>  0 [VirMIDI        ]: VirMIDI - VirMIDI
>                       Virtual MIDI Card 1
>  1 [V8237          ]: VIA8237 - VIA 8237
>                       VIA 8237 with ALC850 at 0x1000, irq 21
>  2 [Revolution51   ]: ICE1724 - M Audio Revolution-5.1
>                       M Audio Revolution-5.1 at 0xb800, irq 16
>  3 [system         ]: USB-Audio - iMic USB audio system
>                       Griffin Technology, Inc iMic USB audio ...
> ```

...

> ## What features do these sound cards have?
>
> There are several ways to find out. For example `/proc/asound/devices` contains an entry for every component of every
>   device ALSA knows about. For the system described above I get
>
> ```
>   0: [ 0]   : control
>   1:        : sequencer
>   8: [ 0- 0]: raw midi
>   9: [ 0- 1]: raw midi
>  10: [ 0- 2]: raw midi
>  11: [ 0- 3]: raw midi
>  32: [ 1]   : control
>  33:        : timer
>  48: [ 1- 0]: digital audio playback
>  49: [ 1- 1]: digital audio playback
>  56: [ 1- 0]: digital audio capture
>  57: [ 1- 1]: digital audio capture
>  64: [ 2]   : control
>  80: [ 2- 0]: digital audio playback
>  81: [ 2- 1]: digital audio playback
>  82: [ 2- 2]: digital audio playback
>  88: [ 2- 0]: digital audio capture
> ```

...

> ## How do I set the default device?
>
> Create a configuration file (either for the whole system at `/etc/asound.conf` or `.asoundrc` in your home directory) containing
>   statements like the following ones:
>
> ```
> defaults.ctl.card 1
> defaults.pcm.card 1
> defaults.timer.card 1
> ```
>
> This file would make card 1 the default. The card number (`1` in this example) is taken from the `/proc/asound/cards file`. For a
>   description of the ALSA configuration file format see the ALSA library
>   API documentation.